# how to allow cors for specific domain on express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I am trying to send a cookie after login via ajax from localhost to a server hosted somewhere else. TO counter the error related to cookies, I use in my axios:

```
var instance = axios.create({ 
   withCredentials: true
});
```

and in expressjs I have this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

So, I am getting this error now

> Failed to load https://foo.herokuapp.com/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

How can I tell express to whitelist my domain or how do I just send back the cookie so I can stay logged in?

To add more info, when I make a post (login) request to the expressjs, it returns a cookie, now my browser does not send the cookie by iself, so that is why I am usiing `withCredentials`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replace the `*` with the origin (`http://localhost:8080` in your example).